# R data.table difference equation (dynamic panel data)

Tags: r, data.table, panel-data

I have a data table with a column v2 with 'initial values' and a column v1 with a growth rate. I would like to extrapolate v2 for years past the available value, by growing the previous value by factor v1. In 'time series' notation v2(t+1)=v2(t)*v1(t), given a v2(0).

The problem is, the year of the initial value may vary by group x in the dataset. In some groups, v2 may be available in multiple years, or not at all. Also, the number of years per group may vary (unbalanced panel). Using the shift function does not help, because it shifts v2 once, and does not reference the previously update value.

```
        x year        v1       v2
     1: a 2012 0.8501072       NA
     2: a 2013 1.0926093 39.36505
     3: a 2014 1.2084379       NA
     4: a 2015 0.8921997       NA
     5: a 2016 0.8023251       NA
     6: b 2012 1.1005287       NA
     7: b 2013 1.0139800       NA
     8: b 2014 1.1539676       NA
     9: b 2015 1.2282501       NA
    10: b 2016 0.8052265       NA
    11: c 2012 0.8866425       NA
    12: c 2013 0.9952566 44.30377
    13: c 2014 0.9092020       NA
    14: c 2015 1.0295864 15.04948
    15: c 2016 0.8812966       NA
```

The value of V2, x=a, year=2014 should be 39.36*1.208, and in 2015 that answer times 0.89.

The following code, in a set of loops, works and does what I want:

```
    ivec<-unique(DT[,x])
    for (i in 1:length(ivec)) {
       tvec<-unique(DT[x==ivec[i] ,y])
         for (t in 2:length(tvec)) {
           if (is.na(DT[x==ivec[i] & y==tvec[t], v2])) {
              DT[x==ivec[i] & y==tvec[t],v2:=DT[x==ivec[i] & y==tvec[(t-1)],v2]*v1]
           }
         }
      }
```

Comment: What to do when `v2` is available in multiple years?

Comment: In case of multiple values of v2 available in a group, only the missing needs to be updated, and the next available v2 starts a new sequence for updating.

Comment: The following code, in a set of loops, works and does what I want:  
ivec<-unique(DT[,x])
for (i in 1:length(ivec)) {
tvec<-unique(DT[x==ivec[i] ,y])
        for (t in 2:length(tvec)) {
      if (is.na(DT[x==ivec[i] & y==tvec[t], v2])) {
        DT[x==ivec[i] & y==tvec[t],v2:=DT[x==ivec[i] & y==tvec[(t-1)],v2]*v1]
       }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DT[, v2:= Reduce(`*`, v1[-1], init=v2[1], acc=TRUE), by=.(x, cumsum(!is.na(v2)))]

#     x year        v1       v2
#  1: a 2012 0.8501072       NA
#  2: a 2013 1.0926093 39.36505
#  3: a 2014 1.2084379 47.57022
#  4: a 2015 0.8921997 42.44213
#  5: a 2016 0.8023251 34.05239
#  6: b 2012 1.1005287       NA
#  7: b 2013 1.0139800       NA
#  8: b 2014 1.1539676       NA
#  9: b 2015 1.2282501       NA
# 10: b 2016 0.8052265       NA
# 11: c 2012 0.8866425       NA
# 12: c 2013 0.9952566 44.30377
# 13: c 2014 0.9092020 40.28108
# 14: c 2015 1.0295864 15.04948
# 15: c 2016 0.8812966 13.26306
```

Comment: This is great. I really don't understand how or why this works, or how I could have worked this out on my own. Time to really read the manuals. (I started in R a week ago, after 35 years working in SAS. Somehow this is related to 'Retain' in SAS.)